# Einstein Activity Capture issues

Tags: einstein, activity

I am having some issues on fixing the status of users in Einstein Activity,

- a few users have "Needs attention" status,
- I already tried on "Resync" and "Reconnect" them but still nothing has changed.
- I also logged in as those users and in `Quick Find -> Connected Account -> Email and Calendar Accounts`, I have the email of the user with and a message that it says

  ```
  "There’s a problem with this account. Try reconnecting it. 
   If you need help, contact your Salesforce admin."
  ```
- but no like a "reconnect/reset" button or anything. Ha s anybody had this issue before and being able to fix it?